# Is this imbalance possible?

Tags: grammar

> Below is a timeline of what you should do if you were injured at work: [...]
>
> [(Source)](http://goo.gl/fpBrqJ)

This is a subjunctive sentence, but this "should" is not subjunctive.
It is like "You should do it now!"

Is this imbalance possible?

Answer (score 1):

> "Should" is most commonly used to make recommendations or give advice. It can also be used to express obligation as well as expectation. [Source](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/should.html)

The sentence you have quoted is a very common use of "should."

"Should" is the past tense of the word "shall." "Shall" used to have a sense of obligation [Source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=should&allowed_in_frame=0), but this sense is retained in "should" but lost in "shall."

Because "should" is originally past tense, I read it as past subjunctive of "shall," agreeing with "were" in the contrary-to-fact conditional.

Answer (score -1):

As you suspected, the tense progression in that sentence is not grammatically correct.  Possible corrections include:

1. > Below is a timeline of what you should do if you **are** injured at work:

   This is the most natural and straightforward formulation.  If A happens, then you should do B.
2. > Below is a timeline of what you **should have done** if you were injured at work:

   This is what you might write in a retrospective analysis of what went wrong in a response to a workplace accident.  (Writing such a report addressed in the second person would be extremely confrontational, though!)
3. > Below is a timeline of what you should do if you **were to be** injured at work:

   This is what the author of the ungrammatical sentence was probably meaning to say.  [*Were to* + verb](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html) is a special expression that means "in the unlikely event that …".  Basically, it's a more hypothetical form of *if*.  Expressing the sentence this way avoids implying that the reader is likely to be injured at work, and more "polite" than (1).  Unfortunately, the author screwed it up.